# Criando condição dentro da função map em javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Estou com dois problemas relacionados à função map/filter.

Estou pegando dados de um data structure do google e eles seguem o schema.org, porém, no meu caso, uma informação específica nem sempre está no array do elemento que estou utilizando para fazer o map(), de forma mais clara:

- Todos os elementos possuem o item.title, o item.link e o item.snippet
- Nem todos os elementos possuem o item.pagemap.localbusiness

O primeiro problema é que o localbusiness é um array de objetos, então, eu não estava conseguindo pegar os elementos dele diretamente, então, pensei em utilizar o seguinte código:

```
placesInfo = response.data.items.map((item) => {
    return {
        title: item.title,
        link: item.link,
        snippet: item.snippet,
        // metatags: item.pagemap.metatags,
        // ratings: item.pagemap.aggregaterating
        localbusiness: item.pagemap.localbusiness.reduce((items) => { items.item }),
    }})

placesInfoMap = placesInfo.map((item) => {
    return {
        title: item.title,
        link: item.link,
        snippet: item.snippet,
        name: item.localbusiness.name,
        email: item.localbusiness.email,
        telephone: item.localbusiness.telephone,
        address: item.localbusiness.address
    }
})
```

Um exemplo do que essa função retorna no console.log():

```
{title: 'Barbeshop - Curso de Barbeiro Elite',
link: 'https://business.google.com/website/barbeshop-curso-de-barbeiro-elite',
snippet: 'Barbeshop - Curso de Barbeiro Elite. Aberto hoje até 20:00. Solicitar cotação\n' +
  'Ligar ... Lucas Evangelista de Oliveira Franco, 45A - Aterrado. Volta Redonda - \n' +
  'RJ.',
name: 'Barbeshop - Curso de Barbeiro Elite',
email: undefined,
telephone: undefined,
address: 'Avenida Lucas Evangelista de Oliveira Franco, 45A - AterradoVolta Redonda - RJ27215-070Brasil'},
```

response.data.items retorna um array com elementos assim:

```
{
    kind: 'customsearch#result',
    title: 'Restaurante 41 - Restaurante em Vila Santa Cecília',
    htmlTitle: '<b>Restaurante</b> 41 - <b>Restaurante</b> em Vila Santa Cecília',
    link: 'https://business.google.com/website/restaurante41',
    displayLink: 'business.google.com',
    snippet: 'Sou de Minas Gerais estivemos em volta redonda e almoçamos neste otimo \n' +
      'restaurante muito bom comida Boa atendimento bom ..gostamos. - Luciano s.',
    htmlSnippet: 'Sou de Minas Gerais estivemos em <b>volta redonda</b> e almoçamos neste otimo <br>\n' +
      '<b>restaurante</b> muito bom comida Boa atendimento bom ..gostamos. - Luciano s.',
    cacheId: 'p-eg18u63BsJ',
    formattedUrl: 'https://business.google.com/website/restaurante41',
    htmlFormattedUrl: 'https://business.google.com/website/<b>restaurante</b>41',
    pagemap: {
      cse_thumbnail: [Array],
      metatags: [Array],
      cse_image: [Array],
      localbusiness: [Array]
    }
  },
```

Dessa forma eu estava conseguindo retirar os elementos do localbusiness logo após o primeiro map e remontar o array que eu gostaria, porém, percebi que quando testei com outros dados que não continham o localbusiness, o código quebrou.

A minha ideia era tentar utilizar uma função if dentro do map mas não sei se é possível...
Acredito que possa haver formas melhores de fazer o que eu fiz sem toda essa gambiarra...

Outro problema é que esses dados são gerados como json e eu estou transformando eles pra csv ao final de tudo, então, mesmo quando o map não encontra o name, email, telephone e adress eu precisava que esses valores fossem preenchidos pelo menos como um campo em branco ou null e eu não sei como garantir que esses valores vão ser preenchidos, porque o exemplo acima, no json que eu gero fica dessa forma:

```
{"title":"Barbeshop - Curso de Barbeiro Elite","link":"https://business.google.com/website/barbeshop-curso-de-barbeiro-elite","snippet":"Barbeshop - Curso de Barbeiro Elite. Aberto hoje até 20:00. Solicitar cotação\nLigar ... Lucas Evangelista de Oliveira Franco, 45A - Aterrado. Volta Redonda - \nRJ.","name":"Barbeshop - Curso de Barbeiro Elite","address":"Avenida Lucas Evangelista de Oliveira Franco, 45A - AterradoVolta Redonda - RJ27215-070Brasil"}
```

Ou seja, o email e o telephone não foram preenchidos.

Espero que dê pra entender e espero que alguém me salve!

Comment: o que retorna: `response.data.items`

Comment: Atualizei no post porque não dava pra colocar tudo aqui no comentário

Comment: é porque o dado é um `array` entendeu? então se vai pegar alguma posição?

Comment: exemplo: `telephone: item.localbusiness[0].telephone,`? talvez seja isso. eu não sei o que tem dentro de `item.localbusiness`?

Comment: Então, no caso eu estou pegando o title, link, snippet e o pagemap.localbusiness mas preciso tirar as coisas de dentro do localbusiness e já acrescentar no array principal, eu até consegui remontar algo agora mas quando o pagemap.localbusiness não existe o código quebra

Comment: Arthur você precisa colocar tudo que pode acontecer! só isso eu não consigo responder!

Comment: name: item.pagemap.localbusiness.map((item) => {
                   return item.name
            }),
            email: item.pagemap.localbusiness.map((item) => {
                return item.email
             }),
             telephone: item.pagemap.localbusiness.map((item) => {
                 return item.telephone
             }),
             address: item.pagemap.localbusiness.map((item) => {
                 return item.address
             }),

Acrescentei esses maps no placesInfo e apaguei o placesInfoMap mas o código continua quebrando qnd n tem localbusiness

Comment: sim isso é um `array`: `item.pagemap.localbusiness.map`! isso eu sei mas, eu não sei o seu objetivo

Comment: "localbusiness":[{"name":"Janaina Cabelereira"}]
Dentro do local business é dessa forma, nem todos os campos são preenchidos e as vezes não existe o localbusiness

Comment: você precisa testar se a chave existe e assim sucessivamente para então montar o sua lista de objeto

Comment: Como eu faria isso? Tentei jogar um if dentro do map mas não funcionou

Comment: Entendi, consegui fazer funcionar, valeu cara! me salvou!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um exemplo minimo onde primeiro busca se a chave do objeto existe para depois associar o seu valor ou `null` para uma determinada chave:

```js
const isExist = (obj, name) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).includes(name);
}

const arr = [
  { name: 't 1', item: { source: 1 }},
  { name: 't 2', item: {  }},
  { name: 't 3', item: {  }}
]

const b = arr.map(m => {
  return {
    name: m.name,
    item: isExist(m.item, 'source') ? m.item.source: null
  }
});

console.log(b);
```

e nesse caso se verificou se `source` existe se sim pega o valor dele se não passa `null`, e assim sucessivamente deve ser feito aonde o valor pode existir ou não.

<sub>Referencia: [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)</sub>

Comment: Beleza, muito obrigado! Tinha feito algo próximo a isso mas a forma como você fez ta mais simples, vou tentar implementar!